# why does the score matrix influence the E value (BLAST)

Tags: sequence-alignment, blast

When I align two HBB protein sequences wich have 80% identity, I used two kind of score matrices: Blosum62 and PAM30, to figure out the impact on my results.

I noticed that the bit score is higher when I used PAM30 instead of BLOSUM62, which makes sense because PAM30 is based on more closely related species.

However I don't understand why the E-values differs from each other:

> PAMP62: Bit score: 251, E value: 8 * 10^91
>
> PAM30: Bit score: 258, E value: 6*10^82

**Question**: I don't understand why the E-value changes when using an other scoring matrix?

thankyou,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this BLAST tutorial by Steve Altschul will be helpful:  [The Statistics of Sequence Similarity Scores](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/BLAST/tutorial/Altschul-1.html)

There is also the [BLAST book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596002992.do) by Mark Yandell and Ian Korf.

Comment: The Altschul article is definitely what you should look at as it's on the BLAST website. There is one relevant section entitled: "The choice of substitution scores" and another entitled "The PAM and BLOSUM amino acid substitution matrices". Have fun digesting them!